# How to remove multi line code in java / netbeans?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, code-cleanup

I've got a lot of code that is segmented into separate lines in netbeans. I believe it's auto formatting it and when I change any formatting in the editor options it seems to not like it.

An example would be I have the following:

```
private String letters[] = new String[]{"A",
       "B"};
```

And I want it all to be the following:

```
private String letters[] = new String[]{"A", "B"};
```

I've tried online beautifiers and everything seems to leave it seperated. Any ideas / quick fixes ?

Thanks!!

EDIT: Still having issues with this. It's easy to do the reverse and seperate the lines when "Too long" but it doesn't seem like netbeans has a built in way of doing this. I may have to explore other options.

Comment: Can you add the lines that were made into multi lines?

Comment: @Mark - How do you mean? Sorry I'm not following.

Comment: Are you trying to disable NetBeans line wrapping but retain other auto formatting features?

Comment: @Mark - So it's disabled based on the below comment; but I'd like to clean up the current code that HAS the above issue (Where it's split into two lines).

Comment: try to change the ```Right Margin``` value of NetBeans. -> https://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Screenshot-at-2012-01-11-111126.png

Comment: @Mark - I tried that as well. It will work for future but doesn't reformat previous.

Comment: Did you ```CTRL + SHIFT + F``` the previous file?

Comment: CTRL SHIFT F doesn't do anything. ALT SHIFT F does format but it doesn't fix the above.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood from your description

```
 CTRL + SHIFT + F
```

with keyboard combination should be ok

Comment: Hey, I think you're shooting for ALT + SHIFT + F -- And it uses the built in format which seems to be set to pull these apart rather than combine. Thanks for the try!